# Need help debugging this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error when I login:

```
NoMethodError in Videos#index

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/videos/_video.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm not sure why I get this error because my application worked fine earlier... Here is the _video.html.erb file. Line 3 is what's driving the error:

```
1: <%= div_for video do %>
2: <div class='voting_div'> 
3:   <%= link_to "&uArr;".html_safe, video_votes_path( :video_id => video.id, :type => "up" ), :method => :post, :remote => true, :class => "up_arrow round #{current_user && current_user.votes_for(video).value == 1 ? 'voted' : 'unvoted' }" %>
4:   <div id='vote_display' class = 'round'>
5:     <p id='votes'>
6:      <%= video.vote_sum %>
```

How should I fix this error? What code would you like me to post so this can be ironed out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an empty response for `current_user.votes_for(video)`. Also, `current_user.votes_for(video)` implies the result will be a collection, if that's not true I'd change it to `user#vote_for(video)` instead.

```
<%= link_to "&uArr;".html_safe, ... :class => "up_arrow round #{current_user && (vote = current_user.votes_for(video)) && vote.value == 1 ? 'voted' : 'unvoted' }" %>
```

Comment: wow! that fixed it! why does your code work and why didn't mine work?

Comment: You were getting back a nil result for `votes_for`. Mine pulls the vote first, then calls `vote.value` only if it's not nil.

Comment: Ok, I don't see how it's different though... it's doing what I did, but in two steps, not sure why I would have the error...

Comment: if `(vote = current_user.votes_for(video))` returns nil then the expression immediately evalutes to false and never even evaluates `vote.value == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be this:

`<%= link_to "&uArr;".html_safe, video_votes_path( :video_id => video.id, :type => "up" ), :method => :post, :remote => true, :class => "up_arrow round #{current_user && current_user.votes_for(video).try(:value) == 1 ? 'voted' : 'unvoted' }" %>`